# Find Last Modified File and get the result in a variable

Tags: linux, bash

I need to search for a specific `.iso` file in a Directory. This one is the last one modified, and I will have only one result returned. I want this result to be stored in a Variable.

My script then contains :

`$MYFILE = find . -type f -name '*.iso' -printf '%p\n' | sort -r | head -n 1`

But this gives a file which is not up to date (22 of August, instead of 14 of October for instance) ...

Is there anything wrong with that way to go ? I don't quite understand why I got a file that is neither the last one nor the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Find" does not sort the files and "sort -r" will only do a reverse alphabetical sort.

If you print the modification time with find, you will be able to sort on modification time and extract the file name (even if the files are in different sub directories):

```
MYFILE=$(find -name "*.iso" -type f -printf "%Ts %p\n" | sort -n | tail -1 | sed -r -e 's/^[0-9]+ //')
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess your `sort -r` does alphabetical sort on file names and not based on modified time.

Try this:

```
find . -name "*.iso" -type f | xargs ls -tr | tail -1
```